# Office2007 Setupstyle with WIX

Tags: wix, coding-style

any idea, how to make a setup which looks like Office2007-Setup? For example the blue buttons which become golden on hover etc.?
Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would take *A LOT* of work because Office 2007 isn't using native/internal MSI UI capabilities.  It is instead implementing a custom external UI handler.

[Beyond the Native Windows Installer User Interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/07/23/442584.aspx)

Comment: Same here. :-)   I keep hoping that someone will release a extensible WPF based Embedded External UI handler. 

Microsoft clearly has the business needs (  support Unicode languages and provide very slick looking UI for many installs ) to invest in these things but most of us deal with the internal UI as 'good enough'.

Comment: Yes, of course because the installer is not so important to spend much time just in the UI...
I'm looking forward to hear something about Microsoft soon (too hopeful? ;) )